# How the "OK" message looks like?

Tags: tcp, modbus

I have a device that sends data to a server.

```
            Data
[ Client ]  == >  [ Server ]
```

After the validation on the server I want to return a message:

```
            OK
[ Client ] < == [ Server ]
```

Is there a standard "OK" message to return? And an "ERROR" message? How does it looks like? (e.g. ":0011", ":110F")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got to design an application-level protocol.  TCP is a byte stream, so even the definition of "Data" in your client->server piece needs some protocol so that the receiver can know what bytes make up the data (when to stop reading).

A couple of common types of protocols are...

- Length-delimited chunks.  Every message starts with a 16 or 32-bit length prefix.  Then that many bytes follow.  The length needs to be in a defined byte order (see [htons, ntohs, etc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htons)).  Everyone who uses this protocol knows to read the length prefix then read that many bytes.  Having defined that "chunk" on the network, you might put a header on the contents of the chunk.  Maybe a message type (ACK, NAK, Data, etc) followed by some contents.
- ASCII newline delimited.  Each message is a line of ASCII (or UTF8, etc) text.  It ends at a newline.  Newline endings for the lines play the same role as the length prefix for the chunks above.  You then define what's in each line (like space or comma-delimited ASCII/UTF8/whatever fields).  Somewhere in that you'd define what data looks like, ACK, etc.

I'm sure you could come up with other ideas, but that's the basic job: defining your application-level protocol on top of TCP's byte stream.

Comment: So if I understood there isn't a default message for "ACK", I have to create a message and on the data field make my own "ACK".

Comment: There are some low-level ACK's built into the TCP protocol.  But that's only between the OS-level TCP implementations on the two hosts.  That's not going to be useful for an app-level confirmation of goodness/badness of the exchange.  TCP is a stream of bytes -- nothing more.  There isn't even such a thing as a "message", much less a "default ACK message".  You have to build any higher-level protocol on top of the TCP byte stream.