# Sending files and messages over same TCP connection

Tags: tcp

Is it possible to send various things like messages and files over single TCP connection at the same time?

For example, I want to send text commands during file sending. Is it possible without slowing down connection too much? If this is possible, how would I achieve this? Do I need to send it in packets with description ID of each packet?

Or is it best to open two separate connections?

Answer (score 0):

See [How the "OK" message looks like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440569/how-the-ok-message-looks-like/4442224#4442224) for a discussion of how to "frame" messages/whatever over a TCP connection.